# Haskell newtype, but keep old functions

Tags: haskell

I want to define a type of "Ideal" which is a list but with some structure. Numeric prelude already defines instances of `Ring` for lists, but they're not using the definitions of addition and multiplication I want. So I think in this instance I should say

```
newtype Ideal a = Ideal [a]
```

This works fine, but now it gives me an error if I try to do, say `take 5 $ Ideal [0..]`.

Is there a way that I can keep the functions I want and only override the definitions I explicitly override?

Answer (score 11):

If you're not too set on things being *completely* automatic, you could use the utility functions in [the `newtype` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype), e.g. something like `over Ideal $ take 5`.

**Edit:** Also, as an aside, it's not too hard to extend the functions from the `newtype` package to handle other cases. For example, I had these definitions lying around:

```hs
infixl 3 ./
(./) :: (Newtype n o) => (o -> t) -> (n -> t)
(./) fx = fx . unpack

liftN f x = pack $ f ./ x
liftN2 f x y = pack $ f ./ x ./ y
liftN3 f x y z = pack $ f ./ x ./ y ./ z
```

Not actually the best design for such combinators, I suspect, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 7):

For plain functions, no. You'll have to provide your own definitions.

However, for functions that belong to a type class, you can use the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension to expose the type classes you want from the underlying type of a `newtype`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
newtype MyState a = MyState (State Int a)
    deriving (Monad)
```